# what is the Data rate (send and recieve) for E1 link at same time between two computers in two offices

Tags: wireless-networking

what is the the send and receive data transfer rate of E1 link between two computers between two offices. suppose i am sitting at office A and copying a file from computer B in second off office which is receiving 2 Mbps and at same time i am send a file to computer to same computer what is will be the speed. will it be 2 Mbps or  will it decrease my copying rate.

regards

Answer (score 1):

E1 allows 2Mbps in each direction, so you should only observe minor speed drops due to the aknowdgement packets.